# DNS not working over DSL

Tags: networking, dns, pppoe

I connect to Internet via a PPPOE connection that i configured manually as below:

```
/etc/ppp/peers/hamyar
#hamyar:
noipdefault 
defaultroute 
replacedefaultroute 
hide-password 
noauth 
persist 
plugin rp-pppoe.so eth0 
user "********" 
usepeerdns
```

when I connect via "pon hamyar" everything works fine(i have ping response from any IP) except pinging to names like google.com and i cannot open it from my browser.
what shall i do?

here's log information:

```
Connected to 00:09:44:6c:e8:1a via interface eth0 
Using interface ppp0 
Connect: ppp0 <--> eth0 
PAP authentication succeeded 
peer from calling number 00:09:44:6C:E8:1A authorized 
replacing old default route to eth0 [192.168.1.20] 
local IP address 178.173.139.142 
remote IP address 80.191.122.18 
primary DNS address 80.191.122.5 
secondary DNS address 4.2.2.1
```

Comment: what happens if do add google DNS as well: 8.8.8.8

Comment: in my wired lan nothin, and in /etc/ppp/resolv.conf would be overwrited to: nameserver 80.191.122.5 and nameserver 4.2.2.1       becauseof usepeerdns i think...

Comment: solved by setting system dns but still don't know why dsl dns did not work

Comment: It looks odd to me that the local IP and remote IP addresses are so disimilar. Can you `ping 80.191.122.18` ? Would you mind describing what you did to fix the problem in an answer and then accepting it to help others with this problem in the future?

Comment: i'm new here and i don't have enough points to answer my own question but i'll do that as soon as i can

Answer (score 1):

resolv.conf will be overwritten by network manager. You could edit your connection to set other DNSs servers than what your ISP gives you throw DHCP. For this run `nm-connection-editor`, choose your DSL connection, then *IPv4 Settings* tab, then on *Additional DNS servers* add [Cloudflare DNS servers](https://1.1.1.1/) *1.1.1.1, 1.0.0.1* or Google DNS servers: *8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4*, or OpenDNS servers: *208.67.222.222, 208.67.220.220*.

On command line you could test a DNS server with:

```
nslookup sitetotest.com DNSserverIPtotry
```

Notice that a ping is an ICMP package and DNS is an application protocol, so they live on a different layer of TCP/IP stack of protocols. A server/host could respond to a ping without having any service listening on any port.