# Changing DNS nameservers with systemd-resolve doesn't persist

Tags: networking, server, dns, resolv.conf, systemd-resolved

let me start by saying that I'm not sure whether I'm running Ubuntu server or Ubuntu desktop, that being said, my 'server' is running on a VPS.

Here is the output of `lsb_release -a`:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

I'm trying to override the default DNS name servers, and I've half succeeded. I have run `systemd-resolve --interface eth0 --set-dns 10.13.13.5 --set-domain test.test` to set 10.13.13.5 as a nameserver for the domain test.test and then run `service systemd-resolved restart`. I can then ping devices on the test.test domain, having them resolve to the right IP address.

I can confirm the 10.13.13.5 nameserver is in effect by doing `systemd-resolve --status`.

It comes up with this:

```
Link 2 (eth0)
      Current Scopes: DNS            
DefaultRoute setting: yes            
       LLMNR setting: yes            
MulticastDNS setting: no             
  DNSOverTLS setting: no             
      DNSSEC setting: no             
    DNSSEC supported: no             
  Current DNS Server: 10.13.13.5   
         DNS Servers: 213.133.100.100
                      213.133.98.98  
                      213.133.99.99  
          DNS Domain: test.test
```

After a few minutes though, the server will not resolve domain names to any IP addresses on the test.test domain. The `--status` command above now looks like this:

```
Link 2 (eth0)
      Current Scopes: DNS            
DefaultRoute setting: yes            
       LLMNR setting: yes            
MulticastDNS setting: no             
  DNSOverTLS setting: no             
      DNSSEC setting: no             
    DNSSEC supported: no             
  Current DNS Server: 213.133.98.98  
         DNS Servers: 10.13.13.5     
                      213.133.100.100
                      213.133.98.98  
                      213.133.99.99  
          DNS Domain: test.test
```

It's clear what the issue is here, the `Current DNS Server` is being changed... but I'm not sure what's changing it and I'm not sure how to stop it.

My `/etc/resolv.conf` file is linked to `/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf`:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 29 May 19 15:30 /etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf
```

I think I can slightly grasp the way it works although it does confuse me a little... the stub is 127.0.0.53, which is an internal DNS resolver to nameservers you specify in `/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf`, but I'm not sure if this is right.

I would greatly appreciate any help with this as it is annoying being able to resolve things for a few minutes and then they stop working!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you [try `nm-connection-editor`](https://askubuntu.com/a/557382/349837) or [`nmtui`](https://askubuntu.com/a/1174193/349837)?

Comment: Both commands not found.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I configure my DNS settings in Ubuntu server?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/346838/how-do-i-configure-my-dns-settings-in-ubuntu-server)